# AJAX form sending data, PHP form not receiving it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, fancybox

I had this working earlier, but now it doesn't seem to want to pick up the data. It's possible something changed when I was trying to make it stop refreshing the page.

The form submits, but only for certain links. However the data gets sent across as normal. It's extremely strange.

This is the page the data is being sent to. Right now it just accepts the data and posts it for testing. "Text" shows but nothing else.

```
<?php

$ship_id = $_POST['transfer_ship'];
$char_id = $_POST['transfer_character'];
$pos_id = $_POST['transfer_position'];
$requested_by = $_POST['transfer_player'];

echo 'Success';
echo $ship_id;
echo $char_id;
echo $requested_by;
echo $pos_id;
echo $char_owner;
echo 'Text';
```

This is the form it's being sent from. It's part of a PHP UL series that's running. For the first result, the jQuery fires, I get the "Success" alert. For any of the other li links the data apparently gets sent (I use the F12 dev tools in Chrome, under Network, to see the header) but the page above either doesn't receive it or doesn't do anything with it.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#transfer').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert('Success!');
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Form and UL:

```
<ul>
<?php
        while(list($key, $val) = each ($arrayresult))
        {

            echo '<a href="#inline' .$val. '" class="fancybox"><li style="padding: 2px; margin: 0px; list-style: none;">';
            echo '<img src="../images/profilepics/'.$charpic.'" style="float: right; padding-left: 10px; width: 40px;" />';
            echo '<h2>'.$val.' Position</h2>';
            echo '<p>Click here to apply for this position.</p>';
            echo '</li></a>';

            echo '<div id="inline' .$val. '" style="display:none;">';
            echo '<h1>Request Character Transfer</h1>';
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '<form id="transfer" action="TransferRequest.php" method="post">';
            echo '<label for="transfer_character">Character to Transfer</label>';
            echo '<select id="transfer_character" name="transfer_character">';
            echo '<option value="">Select Character</option>';

            $request_character_query = "SELECT * FROM character_database WHERE character_active ='1' AND user_id = $user_id ORDER BY character_firstname DESC";
            $request_character_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $request_character_query);

            /*** loop over the results ***/
            foreach($request_character_result as $charrow)
            {
              /*** create the options ***/
              echo '<option value="'.$charrow['character_id'].'">'. $charrow['character_firstname'] . " " . $charrow['character_surname'] . '</option>'."\n";
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<p>Applying for the '.$val.' position on the '.$shipname.'</p>';
            echo '<p>If this is correct, please submit below</p>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$val.'" name="transfer_position">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$ship_id.'" name="transfer_ship">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$user_id.'" name="transfer_player">';
            echo '<input value="Submit Request" type="submit" class="styled">';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I have my htaccess file removing the .php extension, but I had .php on the redirect link for ajax. So it was hitting the .php page then redirecting WITHOUT the POST data.